# Two pass C preprocessing?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to get the **C** preprocessor (GCC) to run two passes, to fully expand macros?

I'm trying to define macros that support port I/O on a microcontroller using abstract names for pins:

```
#define LED_RED E, (1<<6)

#define SetPin(port, mask)    PORT ## port ## SET = (mask)
#define ClearPin(port, mask)  PORT ## port ## CLR = (mask)
#define ReadPin(port, mask)   (PORT ## port) & (mask)
```

Then in my code:

```
SetPin(LED_RED);
ClearPin(LED_RED);
result = ReadPin(LED_RED);
```

This is meant to expand to:

```
PORTESET = (1<<6);
PORTECLR = (1<<6);
result = (PORTE) & (1<<6);
```

This doesn't compile - I get:

> error: macro "SetPin" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given.

Although this does compile and work OK:

```
SetPin(E, (1<<6));
```

So...how to get the **C** compiler to fully expand these macros?

Or, if not that, how to make this kind of thing work?

Comment: @MichałWalenciak: macros are perfectly appropriate for embedded C for bit toggling.

Comment: I've been using c++ with templates and it was perfect also ;)

Comment: If you need complex macros, you might consider some other preprocessor (e.g. [GPP](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP)). Don't forget meta-programming: you can, you perhaps you should, generate your C code from something higher level (perhaps using simple `awk` scripts to generate C code in header files).

Comment: @MichałWalenciak: Yes, and in Ruby you can even do meta-programming. This question is about C, though.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak: That comment is not useful. This is a C question and macros are part of the language. They are also perfectly valid for C++ in some aspects. In any way, they have a different field of usage than templates in C++.

Comment: @undur_gongor: Meta programming is possible with C (by generating C code elsewhere). A lot of complex C programs have some of their C files generated by other means (`yacc` or `bison`, `autoconf`, `m4`, `gpp` etc....). Generating C code is a very common habit (e.g. adding a rule in your `Makefile` using `awk` to generate some C things...). The [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler is generating C or C++ code internally since twenty years ago at least.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: `yacc`, `bison`, `m4`, ... are _not_ part of the C language, so that it not "metaprogramming in C". As much as generating machine code by other tools is not metaprogramming.

Comment: @Olaf: [gpp](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP) is not `/lib/cpp`, and today the preprocessor is inside the compiler.  `gpp` is a general purpose preprocessor with a nicer look-&-feel than  `m4`

Comment: [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) is simply generating or processing some programs as data. You don't need any homoiconic language for that (even if it then much easier). m4 has been used for metaprogramming tasks related to C code even in SunOS3.2 (1985).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Thank you for that information. I always thought meta-programming and reflection are the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to pass the arguments through an additional macro.

```
#define LED_RED E, (1<<6)
#define SetPin2(port, mask)    PORT ## port ## SET = (mask)
#define SetPin(x) SetPin2(x)

SetPin(LED_RED);
```

This is due to the order of macro replacement:

1. First, the arguments of a function-like macro are identified. This already
   fails if the number of arguments is wrong (as in your code).
2. Then, the argument tokens are put into the replacement list. Unless    they are next to `##` or `#`, they get macro-expanded
   before.
3. Finally, the resulting replacement list is scanned for further macro replacements.

With the additional macro "in between", the 2nd steps gets the chance to replace `LED_RED`.